# Quick way to update the value of column in 100+ rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 fields

```
Example_Table
-------------
ID (identity)
SomeKey
SomeValue
```

There are probably 150 values saved into this table. Apparently, all but 6 of those values has changed -_-' I have an excel document containing the new values, and am not looking forward to trying to do updates on it all. As a programmer, I can't help but feel there's a better method than doing it manually, or worse yet dropping the table and rebuilding it with the new values.

Does anyone know of a quick way to do a mass update like that? The new values in the spreadsheet are logically sorted / ordered by the key (desc) that they are paired with.

Comment: You're talking about updating the contents of the SomeValue column, not the ID column, right? What version of Management Studio do you have?

Comment: i quess youll have to write some code, (vba will be best solution if you have an excel file)

Comment: @Eugen personally I think a little copy/paste/typing within Excel or within SSMS will be far easier than writing vba code. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio**

1. Make sure the columns in Excel are lined up with SomeValue first and SomeKey (or ID) second.
2. Highlight the entire range, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, switch to a new query window in Management Studio, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
3. Highlight your cursor at the beginning of the first line, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and use the down-arrow to scroll to the last line.
4. Type:

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.Example_Table SET SomeValue = '
   ```
5. Repeat 3. placing your cursor after the value, and type:

   ```
   ' WHERE SomeKey =
   ```

Now you've got a series of UPDATE statements you can run individually or altogether.

**If you are using a previous version**

1. Make sure the columns in Excel are lined up with SomeValue first and SomeKey (or ID) second.
2. Insert a new column before SomeValue.
3. In the first row of the new column, type:

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.Example_Table SET SomeValue = '
   ```
4. In the lower-right corner of that cell, drag with a cross to repeat the value across all applicable rows.
5. Repeat 2. and 3. in between SomeValue and SomeKey, this time typing:

   ```
   ' WHERE SomeKey =
   ```
6. Repeat 4. for the new column.
7. Highlight the entire range, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, switch to a new query window in Management Studio, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
8. You may need to search and replace for Tab characters. Highlight one, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and make sure `Replace with:` is an empty string, then click `Replace All` (unless your data might naturally contain tabs).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers! This is the one I went with. You are a life saver, Aaron! =D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the spreadsheet data to a new workbook.  Delete everything except the column with the keys and the column with the values.

Insert new columns as needed between them, and add UPDATE sql code between them.

You'll wind up with something like

```
Column A                               Column B                 Column C           Col D
UPDATE Example_Table SET SomeValue = '|   value from column B |' WHERE SomeKey = '| value from column D '
```

(Sorry about the markup - formatting help would be welcome)

With a little cut & paste you'll have 150 update statements.  Copy them into SQL Server and execute.  You may want to paste them into notepad or equivalent first, to check for tabs etc.

It should be a 5 minute job.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to import your data in the Excel document into SQL Server.  Microsoft lists a few ways [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)  Personally, I have always used the import wizard that comes with management studio.

Either way you should end up with a table with the keys and values in it.  Then you can use a query like this:

```
UPDATE mt
SET Value = temp.Value
FROM myTable mt
INNER JOIN importedTable temp on mt.Key = temp.Key
```